# Any good WPF debuggers/inspectors out there for VS 2010?

Tags: wpf

I found [Mole](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/MoleForVisualStudioEdit.aspx), which looks like exactly the thing I need, but alas there is no VS 2010 support.  I'm not sure if the project is being maintained either.  Are there other tools for live debugging/inspecting of a XAML control tree?  I'm looking for something like firebug for XAML...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest version of [Snoop on CodePlex](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) supports up to .NET 4 and x64. It runs outside of VS so it doesn't matter what version you're using and in fact you don't even need VS at all. You can just run it against pretty much any WPF app. I tried Mole a few times but never really got into it because Snoop is so much better, especially if you're doing MVVM and can't easily break into the debugger with an appropriate scope to see the UI.

Answer (score 1):

I like [Snoop](http://blois.us/Snoop/)

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [Mole 2010](http://www.molosoft.com/) - they have added a ton of new features - I can't get over how much more it does and how nice the UI is. They'd done a bang up job on it.